# Python Telethon get_messages offset

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm using `Telethon` in my `Python` project. I'm using this code to get messages from a Group in Telegram:

```
full_msg_list = self.client.get_messages(GROUPID, limit=200)
```

Is there any way to get the next 200 messages from the group?

Comment: Note you could also just use 400 as a limit, to get the first 200 and the next 200.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages) you can use `add_offset`:

```py
full_msg_list = self.client.get_messages(GROUPID, limit=200, add_offset=200)
```

Edit:

For a more reliable offset, even when new messages arrive, use `offset_id` instead:

```py
full_msg_list = self.client.get_messages(GROUPID, limit=200, offset_id=200)
next_200_list = self.client.get_messages(GROUPID, limit=200, offset_id=full_msg_list[-1].id)
```

Comment: It's probably a better idea to use `offset_id`. That way, even if new messages arrive, the offset will remain valid.